# How to write a custom query / route in feathersjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, hook, feathersjs

I feel like I am being stupid here and misunderstanding the docs.

I am trying to use [feathersjs](http://feathersjs.com/) for the first time and I am slowly finding my way around.

I can create (for examples sake) a /messages route using a service generator which allows me to GET all messages.

What I am trying to do is filter the query (either in a before hook I assume, or possibly a custom route). For example only getting messages sent on a particular day, or if the correct relationships were set up - only getting messages between the logged in user and one other user.

effectively I want [this](https://docs.feathersjs.com/databases/querying.html) applied to my /messages route but I am not entirely sure where I am supposed to put it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Okay I am not entirely sure if this is the correct way to do it but I can achieve what I wanted by mounting a before hook like so:

```
module.exports = function() {
    return function(hook) {
        hook.params.query = {
          name: 'peter'
        }
    };
};
```

For example would only return results where the name field is 'peter'

I would prefer to find a way where I could implement more advanced queries than this if possible though.

Comment: You can also query on the client, for example in the browser when going to `http://localhost:3030/messages?name=peter` would also get you all results where the name is `peter`.

Comment: Thanks @Daff this is really good to know and will surely be useful for future usecases. I wanted to do this server side as the set I am actually querying should always be a subset - I don't want the user to ever have access to the full set.

Comment: Makes sense. What you did in the answer is exactly how it's done then.

Comment: Check out this for more advanced conditions: https://docs.feathersjs.com/databases/querying.html
I'm also new to feathers, but i think if you need more complex queries you should write your own database wrapper.

Comment: https://docs.feathersjs.com/databases/querying.html - broken link